# can't install yii2 mongodb extension because of driver missing

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

I'm trying to install yii2 mongodb extension, but I have this error when I run composer update

```
Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.1.1 requires ext-mongodb >=1.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.1.0 requires ext-mongodb >=1.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-mongodb ~2.1.0 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-mongodb[2.1.0, 2.1.1].
```

I know I need to have the driver installed but I have it, I know because of this

```
php -i | grep mongo
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mongo.ini,
mongo
mongo.allow_empty_keys => 0 => 0
mongo.chunk_size => 261120 => 261120
mongo.cmd => $ => $
mongo.default_host => localhost => localhost
mongo.default_port => 27017 => 27017
mongo.is_master_interval => 15 => 15
mongo.long_as_object => 0 => 0
mongo.native_long => 1 => 1
mongo.ping_interval => 5 => 5
```

and the extension was installed trought pecl, I have this info when I run

```
pecl info mongo

About pecl.php.net/mongo-1.6.14
===============================
Release Type          PECL-style PHP extension (source code)
Name                  mongo
Channel               pecl.php.net
Summary               MongoDB database driver
Description           This package provides an interface for
                      communicating with the MongoDB database in PHP.
Maintainers           Derick Rethans <derick@php.net> (lead)
                      Hannes Magnusson <bjori@php.net> (lead)
                      Jeremy Mikola <jmikola@php.net> (lead)
Release Date          2016-04-26 16:08:28
Release Version       1.6.14 (stable)
API Version           1.6.14 (stable)
```

what could be reason of the error? any help will be appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, basically I didn't know there are more than one mongo extension to install, the one Yii needs is mongodb extension, I installed that one from homebrew and all is working fine now, thanks!